# Simple program in C++ with Clion "expected `,' or `...' before '&&' token"

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors, c++17, clion

Hi guys I can not solve in the following error that I find in my code:
The error indicated by the IDE refers to the move constructor. The IDE does not report me errors are when I compile it gives me error.

```
Scanning dependencies of target Lab_01

[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Lab_01.dir/main.cpp.obj

In file included from C:\Users\alex\CLionProjects\LabPDS\Lab_01\main.cpp:2:

C:\Users\alex\CLionProjects\LabPDS\Lab_01\Message.h:21: error: expected `,' or `...' before '&&' token

C:\Users\alex\CLionProjects\LabPDS\Lab_01\Message.h:21: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant `Message (const Message&)'

C:\Users\alex\CLionProjects\LabPDS\Lab_01\Message.h:23: error: **expected `,' or `...' before '&&' token**

mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Lab_01.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Lab_01.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Lab_01.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Lab_01] Error 2
```

Can someone help me?

my class main.cpp in line:2 find it the error, in the class Message.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Message.h"

int main() {
    Message m1(10);
    std::cout << m1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

File: Message.h

```
// Created by Alexandro Vassallo on 10/04/2020.

#ifndef LAB_01_MESSAGE_H
#define LAB_01_MESSAGE_H


class Message {

    long id;
    char* data;
    int size;
    static long sId;

    char* mkMessage(int n);

public:
    Message();                                      //Costruttore di Default
    Message(int n);                                 //Costruttore con un solo parametro
    ~Message();                                     //Distruttore
    Message(const Message& source);                 //Costruttore di copia
    Message(Message&& source);                      //Costruttore di movimento
    Message& operator=(const Message& source);      //Operatore di assegnazione
    Message& operator=(Message&& source);           //Operatore di assegnazione di movimento

    long getId() const;

    void setId(long id);

    char *getData() const;

    void setData(char *data);

    int getSize() const;

    void setSize(int size);

    static long getSId();

    static void setSId(long sId);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Message& m);


#endif //LAB_01_MESSAGE_H
```

In line 21 and line 23 above there is the move constructor and the move assigment operator.

File: Message.cpp

```
// Created by Alexandro Vassallo on 10/04/2020.

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Message.h"
long Message::sId = 0;

Message::Message(): id(-1), size(0){
    this->data = mkMessage(0);
}

Message::Message(int n): size(n) {
    this->id= sId++;
    this->data = mkMessage(n);
}

Message::~Message() {
    delete[] data;
}

Message::Message(const Message &source):id(source.id), size(source.size) {
    this->data = new char[size];
    memcpy(this->data,source.data,size);
}

Message::Message(Message &&source) {
    this->id = source.id;
    this->size = source.size;
    this->data = source.data;
    source.id = -1;
    source.size = 0;
    source.data = nullptr;
}

Message &Message::operator=(const Message &source) {

    if(this != &source){
        delete[] this->data;
        this->data = nullptr;
        this->size = source.size;
        this->data = new char[size];
        memcpy(this->data, source.data,size);
    }

    return *this;
}

Message &Message::operator=(Message &&source) {

    if(this != &source){
        delete[] this->data;
        this->size = source.size;
        this->data = source.data;
        source.data = nullptr;
    }

    return *this;
}


long Message::getId() const {
    return id;
}

void Message::setId(long id) {
    Message::id = id;
}

char *Message::getData() const {
    return data;
}

void Message::setData(char *data) {
    Message::data = data;
}

int Message::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

void Message::setSize(int size) {
    Message::size = size;
}

long Message::getSId() {
    return sId;
}

void Message::setSId(long sId) {
    Message::sId = sId;
}

char* Message::mkMessage(int n) {
    std::string vowels ="aeiou";
    std::string consolants = "bcdfghlmnqrstvz";

    char* m = new char[n+1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        m[i] = i%2 ? vowels[rand()%vowels.size()]:consolants[rand()%consolants.size()];
    }
    m[n] = 0;
    return m;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Message& m){
    out << m.getId() << m.getSize() << m.getData();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` and include the output you get when compiling with that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using C++11 or later. Move semantics are not supported by older versions.

Comment: in Cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Lab_01)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Lab_01 main.cpp Message.cpp Message.h)

than using c++17

Comment: @AlexandroVassallo Add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)` to your CMake file to see the actual commands it's using to verify that it's indeed using c++17. If it's   not, you'll get this exact error as shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9RhHWh)

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you, you solved the problem, I installed the latest version of Mingw with c ++ 11/17.

Comment: Great! It was all Enders doing though. I just jumped on his/hers answer.

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)